# Is it possible to call PHP-Script from JavaScript section of JSP page..?

Tags: javascript, php, jsp

I have written following script on server-

```
<?php

//Create an array
$json_response = array();


   // include db connect class
    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

    // connecting to db
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();
    $status = "In Progress";

    $con = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);

    if (!$con) 
    {
        die('Could not connect to database: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    //Query to select pending queries database
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM tbl_query_master WHERE status='".$status."' ORDER BY query_date DESC");

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {        
        $row_array['query_id'] = $row['query_id'];
        $row_array['sender_mobile_no'] = $row['sender_mobile_no'];
        $row_array['sender_name'] = $row['sender_name'];
        $row_array['query_string'] = $row['query_string'];
        $row_array['action_taken'] = $row['action_taken'];        
        $row_array['status'] = $row['status'];
        $row_array['query_date'] = $row['query_date'];
        $row_array['action_date'] = $row['action_date'];
        $row_array['view_status'] = $row['view_status'];
        $row_array['read_status'] = $row['read_status']; 

        //push the values in the array

        array_push($json_response,$row_array);
    }    
   echo json_encode($json_response); 
?>
```

Above script returns one JSON object which is useful for me in JavaScript section of my JSP page, but I don't know how to call php-script from the java script section, so need your guidance for the same. Hope you understand what I'm saying Thank you..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved it using AJAX as follows, I don't know whether performance wise this method is correct or not, but perfectly worked for me. Write the following code in your JavaScript section.

```
var xmlHttp;
        //FUNCTION TO CREATE BROWSER COMPATIBLE OBJECT.
        function createBrowserObject()  
        {               
            if (typeof XMLHttpRequest != "undefined")  //Object for Netscape 5+, Firefox, Opera, Safari,and Internet Explorer 7
            {                       
                    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else if (window.ActiveXObject)  //Version for Internet Explorer 5 and 6.
            {
                xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");  
            }
            if (xmlHttp == null)         //Fails on older and nonstandard browsers
            {
                alert("Browser does not support XMLHTTP Request");
            }
        }

        function getDataChange() 
        {           
            if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 || xmlHttp.readyState == "complete") //Check whether server response came back with no errors.
            {
               //THE RESPONSE FROM SERVER. DO YOUR STUFF WITH xmlHttp.responseText
                alert("Responce= "+xmlHttp.responseText);
                //document.getElementById("cart_div").innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;

            }
        }

        function getData()
        {           
               createBrowserObject();//CREATE BROWSER COMPATIBLE OBJECT.// 

                var url = "http://yourdomain.com/your_script.php";  // URL of server-side resource.
                // Using following way you can send parameter to your script. 
                //url += "?param1=" + param1 + "&param2=" + param2;
                xmlHttp.onreadystatechange =getDataChange;  //ASSIGN RESPONSE HANDLER FUNCTION NAME TO ONREADYSTATECHANGE//
                xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);   //INITIATE GET or POST REQUEST. (Here GET)
                xmlHttp.send(null);    // SEND DATA. (Always null in case of GET.)

        }
```

And finally create event to call "getData()" function. That's it. Thank you..!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your php script is deployed to a web server (apache with php mod) and is triggered by some URL, e.g. `http://localhost/script.php`

Then in your javascript you can do POSt request using jquery:

```
$.getJSON('http://localhost/script.php', function(json) {
  // do what you need with your json data
});
```

Comment: I tried your solution as--                                                 -            function getJSONData()
            {
             alert("Inside JSON ");
             $.getJSON('http://localhost/script.php', function(json)
             {
                // do what you need with your json data
              alert("json= "+json);
             });
             alert("data= "+data);
            }  But it is not showing me the inner alert (i.e. alert("json= "+json);). I have check my URL it is 100% OK. can you please tell me where I'm going wrong..?

Comment: Do you see your expected json when you hit your URL in a browser?

Comment: Yes.., I'm getting expected json when I hit my URL in a browser. So definitly there is no problem in URL and php-script.

Comment: Did you include jquery.js? What version of jquery you are using? Can you see any errors in the javascript console of your browser (Chrome or Firefox)?